# how to make a button fold down two EditTexts below on click

Tags: android

I'm a beginner with short knowledge of programming, I've just started learning android development. I'm making an app and at one of the pages I have to make a certain kind of design that I cannot figure out how to or can't even find them in the internet. Basically, as you can see in the images below, next to the first textview, there's a little arrow. Whenever the user clicks on that arrow, two edittexts should appear below that texview just like in the second image and kind of drag the rest of the textviews down. I'd be really grateful if you guys could help me do this or at least provide me with some information on where to search this kind of problem solution. Thanks.[image]   [image]

Comment: You're going to have to need to use third-party libraries to achieve this. This UI element is called "Accordion" so I'd start by searching for Accordion view libraries for Android. There's a bunch of them.

Comment: Thank you, that's the information i needed, gonna look it up in the internet.

Comment: There's no need for an extra library, it's easy to do this on your own. You didn't show the exact layout elements but I'm guessing that you're using a linear layout for the 5 items in the second image, right? What you need are 2 mini layouts and an `OnClickListener`. When that specific item in the list is clicked, replace the current layout with the expanded version. When it's clicked again, replace it with the folded version again. I did the same thing with a recycler view about a year ago and there are tutorials showing how to do that (google is your friend. ;)).

Comment: I'm using a ConstraintLayout and when i try to move the edit texts into linearlayout as you said, i'm having problems,  i cannot move the elements and its stuck to the roof. I tried googling but most of the exandable views are done with recyclerview, i'm not sure if i can use that in my case, if i do that i have no idea how to implement the design that i have right now

Comment: @ceaiius Please use the "@", otherwise I won't get a notification. The point of a LinearLayout is exactly that: Everything's arranged for you in a vertical/horizontal list. I'd recommend reading up on the different layouts, e.g. on the [official website](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout). If that's not what you want, that's fine, continue using your ConstraintLayout. I too used a RecyclerView but what I suggested should still be possible without: Have 2 layouts and replace them at runtime or even easier: Add both and just set the visibility (see answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Just create your desired layout in xml with 2 edittext below each textview. But make sure You take these 2 edittexts in a single container. Lets say LinearLayout.
Then you would be easily able to show/hide these lineralayout based on the TextView click.

Or If You are using recyclerView, then it would be more easy. In this case, You have to show the 2 edittexts for currently clicked item only and will need to hide for all others